# Nginx - Configure domain and multiple subdmains pointing to same root

Tags: nginx, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

My wish is to configure my site in a such way that:

- company.fr
- collaborator1.company.fr
- collaborator2.company.fr
- ...

the domain and associated subdomains point to the same directory root.

Under the hood I'll use Symfony and the content displayed will depends on the domain or the subdomain requested.

To achieve this goal I'm wondering if I can have a single configuration file:

```
server {
    server_name company.fr collaborator1.company.fr collaborator2.company.fr;
    root /var/www/project/public;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

or if I need to split it into multiple `server` blocks with a similar configuration.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just want to know the right way to configure nginx to achieve what I explained. I tried a single configuration based on what I saw to not just "ask for the solution"... I don't understand why I've been down-voted

Comment: OK, so what is not working?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was simply asking for feedbacks in order to implement those needs correctly. That's why I created a configuration to show you that I did some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using a `server_name` which includes all possible subdomains, if you plan to add them frequently. This way you don't have to change the nginx configuration in order to add a subdomain.

```
server_name *.company.fr;
```

This includes all subdomains, but does not include `company.fr`.

```
server_name .company.fr;
```

This includes all subdomains, and *does* include `company.fr`. Using this would serve any name in the entire domain from this `server`.

Comment: this solution seems to be more flexible because I'll be able to throw a 404 (in PHP) if someone tries a non existing subdomain and I won't need to edit the configuration :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the same, it's correct.

```
server_name company.fr collaborator1.company.fr collaborator2.company.fr;
```